# how to retrieve the data from firebase database in a sorted way in flutter.. something went wrong when I used retrieve it as Map

Tags: flutter, dictionary, dart, firebase-realtime-database

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:lowmium/const/const.dart';
import 'package:lowmium/model/popular_item_model.dart';
import 'package:sortedmap/sortedmap.dart';

Future<List<PopularItemModel>> getMostPopular() async {
  var list = List<PopularItemModel>.empty(growable: true);
  var source = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().child('a').child('b').child(MOST_POPULAR_REF).orderByKey().once();

 // Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = source.value;
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = source.snapshot.value as Map; //firebase_database ver (9.0.4) <- the problem is here 
  values.forEach((key, value) {
    list.add(PopularItemModel.fromJson(jsonDecode(jsonEncode(value))));
  });

return list;

}
```

how to retrieve the data from firebase database in a sorted way in flutter, because the data retrieved in a random way

I tried orderByKey() and it didn't work [like it's ignored]

also, I tried SortedMap Package(https://pub.dev/packages/sortedmap) and it didn't work also

Answer (score 0):

**This works for me (FirebaseFirestore)**

```
CollectionReference _collectionRef =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users');
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _collectionRef.orderBy("dateOfBirth").get();
```

Comment: Sorry but I'm using FirebaseDatabase not FirebaseFirestore ... anyway get() doesn't work also the same problem still up